# EAGLE CAD is not giving option to upload the step file

Tags: eaglecad

I want to add a 3D package (step file ) in my managed library in eagle CAD as shown in the picture:
[image]

Then I right click on High lighted text under 3d package, and click on "view on web".
This opens up this:

[image]
As you can see, no option for uploading the STEP file to map. How to do this? I have followed a dozens of videos on youtube , but for their cases, a clear "UPLOAD" option is present in their webpage. So, how to fix it?

Comment: 3D models are added via Fusion360 into a managed library on library.io, that what you mean?

Comment: can't we add 3d package via eagle?